# How to replace one character after a set of different numbers

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, git-bash, wc

I have been trying to solve this for a while now.

Example of the issue:

> ```
>  4946990 stuffandthings.sql.gz
>  5005868 Hello there.txt
>  1033557 This is an issue.txt
>   303500 That_I need help fixing.txt
>  8737976 Please help.txt
> 99737976 Thanks.txt
> ```

What I'm trying to do:

> ```
>  4946990     stuffandthings.sql.gz
>  5005868     Hello there.txt
>  1033557     This is an issue.txt
>   303500     That_I need help fixing.txt
>  8737976     Please help.txt
> 99737976     Thanks.txt
> ```

and/or this:

> ```
>  4946990 | stuffandthings.sql.gz
>  5005868 | Hello there.txt
>  1033557 | This is an issue.txt
>   303500 | That_I need help fixing.txt
>  8737976 | Please help.txt
> 99737976 | Thanks.txt
> ```

Basically I'm trying to replace the first character after a set of different numbers.

I fetched this "array" or "list" from the GitBash command, "wc -l" (which prints the amount of line numbers inside a text file, along with the text file name next to it). So if there's anyway I could use regex to complete what I want it to do, or if there's a command I'm not seeing in GitBash that could help do this. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
([0-9])[ ]([a-zA-Z])
```

Replace:

```
\1 | \2
```

or:

```
\1     \2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the following expression

```
^(\d+)([ ]+)(.+)$
# look for digits at the beginning of the line -> group 1
# followed by whitespaces                      -> group 2
# and the rest                                 -> group 3
```

And replace the string with `$1 your_replacement_here $3`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tC6lI0/1) (mind the modifiers, especially `m` !).
Btw, +1 for such a lovely nickname...